# declaring a column length of 0 in a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays

I was just wondering if it was legal to declare a 2d ragged array with one or more of the columns having a length of 0. If it was legal, what will it actually do?

Comment: It will be an empty array of length 0. Why?

Comment: Oh, I am just trying to learn Java and I was curious about what would happen.

Comment: Protip: It never hurts to try when learning a new programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes, it is possible. But then there's another question, why would you consider doing this? The reason I ask this is think about what you're trying to do here. An array in which the columns are of length 0 is technically an empty 2D array. I will, however, show how to do what you're asking and what will happen.

```
int[][] arr = new int[2][0]; //initializing a 2x0 array, which is 2 rows of size 0
```

or if you're trying to make a jagged array

```
int[][] arr = { {},{2} }; //this is a 2d array in which the first row has zero columns and the second row has one column
```

But what happens when you try operating on this array? You surprisingly won't get a compiler error, but you will get a runtime error. Suppose I added this line of code and tried running the program,

```
arr[0][0] = 1;
```

The error I would get is this,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
```

because I can't access any elements in a 2d array with columns of size 0.

Comment: OP specifically asked about ragged arrays, so think `int[][] arr = { {}, { 1, 2 } };`

Comment: @Elliott Frisch I see, I will edit my answer to accommodate this. I wasn't familiar with that term before, thank you

Comment: Alright, I fixed my answer again. Sorry about my misunderstanding.